# Facing difficulty with migrating from wordpress to Drupal

Tags: linux, wordpress, drupal

One of my blog was built on WordPress but now I want to use Drupal as the CMS of my blog.
To do so I have deleted all the WordPress files from my server and the Database and MySQL user which are associated with WordPress blog and uploaded the Drupal files in my server directory where the WordPress files were.
But, when I opened the blog it showed the Wordpress blog, though it's been deleted and there should be the Drupal installation interface. So, I have re-checked my server directories and database, there are no WordPress files and WP database is deleted, there are only the Drupal files, but when I go to the blog to install Drupal there is still the WordPress blog, I have checked the blog in many web browsers and there is not cache memory problem.
My hosting server is linux based.
I can't understand what to do? Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like there must be some confusion, maybe your web host is serving a cached version of your site, have you tried asking them to help troubleshoot the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Could you have changed your domain name?  In that case you would have to wait up to 72 hours for DNS propagation.